# Possible definitions of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, definition, big-list

I was wondering how many definitions of exponential functions can we think of. The basic ones could be:

$$e^x:=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
also
$$e^x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1+\frac{x}{n}\bigg)^n$$
or this one:
Define $e^x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\$ as unique function satisfying:
\begin{align}
e^x\geq x+1\\
\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}:e^{x+y}=e^xe^y
\end{align}
Can anyone come up with something unusual? (Possibly with some explanation or references).

Comment: Your second definition is incorrect: the second $\;1\;$ must be $\;x\;$ , and the last one just doesn't make sense as it doesn't define anything at all...

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833962/how-many-different-definitions-of-e-are-there

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558734/what-are-different-approaches-to-introduce-the-elementary-functions

Comment: And https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381397/definition-of-expx

Comment: continued fraction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula#The_exponential_function

Comment: Your last definition is tricky and the existence of such a function is usually proved by showing that this this definition leads to other more suitable ones.

Comment: I was not aware that your last one could actually used as a definition. And I am impressed because I have the habit of making my mathSE answers involving the exponential depend *solely* on these two properties!

Comment: Just today, i discussed this topic with my analysis lecturer, who was also bit unsure, but it suits me well, because we don't need to work with the series, and eventually arrive at it as a Maclaurin series. The problem might be that we work with something which we don't know if exists.

Comment: @Aloizio I'm not sure Community Wiki was warranted here. *[If a question is valuable enough that you believe it belongs on the site, chances are you don’t need it to be community wiki! \[...\] Instead, strive for quality. If you’re unsure a certain question class belongs on the site, don’t tolerate the worst examples — demand that these questions be awesome. \[...\] **questions rarely, if ever, need community wiki.**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/)*

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: the last definition is not very well-known / popular but it is available as one of my questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1776836/72031 and a full development is done at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1776286/72031

Comment: +1.Nice post. I learned many ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Function $t$ in DE $ \dfrac{dt}{dx}=t $.. upto a constant coefficient.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The exponential function is the unique solution of the initial value problem

$y'(x)=y(x) , \quad y(0)=1$.

Answer (score 32):

We can also define $e^x$ as follows:

- the **inverse function** of $\ln x$, defining $\ln x$ independently as follows

$$\ln x := \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$$

- the **unique solution to IVP** $f'(x)=f(x)$ with $f(0)=1$ which existence is guaranteed by [**Existence and Uniqueness” Theorems for first order IVP**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2470958/505767)

Comment: Would an algebraic definition work, along the lines of: An exponential function is a homomorphism $exp \colon (\mathbb{R},+) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\cdot)$? Thus, $exp(r_1+r_2) = exp(r_1) \cdot exp(r_2)$ and $exp(0) = 1$

Comment: And a good candidate for the definition of $\ln x$ would be $\ln x := \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks good point! That's commenti will be useful to the asker and future readers.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n It's not sufficient without an additional assumption such as the function being continuous at some point, or bounded on some interval, etc.  See the comment below Paul Evans's answer.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n: that property is also shared by $a^x$. A careful analysis of the functional equation $f(x+y) =f(x) f(y) $ easentially leads to exponential function, but existence of such a function requires recourse to more traditional definitions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh - I understand. The reason for my interest in a purely algebraic definition is, that a similar $exp()$ is defined for matrices (which I came across in differential geometry), which leads me to speculate that the definition might be generalised more widely into ring-theory, or since that seems to be fashionable, perhaps even category theory. The latter may not even be complete madness - there is the subject of synthetic differential geometry; once I get around to studying that, I may find out, of course.

Answer (score 15):

Throw $n$ balls into $n$ bins uniformly at random, and take $n \to \infty$. Define $\frac{1}{e}$ to be the limiting fraction of empty bins.

A vehicle moves from point $A$ to $B$ with speed always equal to the remaining distance to $B$. Define $1-\frac{1}{e}$ to be the fraction of distance covered after one unit of time.

Given positive $x$, consider a set of independent Bernoulli random variables with $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = x$. As $n \to \infty$ and $\max_i p_i \to 0$, define $e^{-x}$ to be the probability that all are zero.

Answer (score 14):

Define the value at rationals via powers and roots and then show that there is a unique continuous function which agrees with these values.

First define it for the natural numbers:

Define $e^2 = e \times e$, $e^3 = e \times e \times e $, etc.

Now define it for other integers:

$e^0 = 1$, $e^{-n} = \frac{1}{e^n}$, etc.

Now for other rational numbers (getting a bit harder):

$e^{\frac{p}{q}} = \sqrt[q]{e^p}$

Finally for irrational numbers $x$, you will need to prove that this definition evaluated for any sequence of rational numbers which converge to $x$ has a limit and that it is the same for all sequences which converge to $x$.

This is hard, especially the last step, but I think that it fits a common naive idea of what exponentiation is.  We usually learn it in this sequence.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer with something concrete?

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: How do you define $e$ ?

Comment: Good question.  Either just right it down e.g. $e = 2.71828 . . .$ or use one of your first two definitions with $x = 1$.

Comment: You might just define $x^y$ at this point.

Comment: True. My approach is probably more likely if you are trying to define exponentiation and you have not encountered $e$ yet.  In that case, you probably won't be able to do the last stage very formally and will just assume it as obvious.  I did not express it that way as the OP wanted definitions of $e^x$.

Comment: @MichalDvořák: In this approach the introduction to number $e$ is bit unusual. Typically while evaluating derivative of $f(x) =a^x$ one encounters the function $g(a) =\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{a^h-1}{h}$ and one proves that $g$ is strictly increasing with domain $\mathbb {R} ^{+} $ and range $\mathbb{R} $. This guarantees the existence of a positive number $e$ with $g(e) =1$ and surprisingly $e^x$ then turns out to be the inverse of $g$.

Comment: Yes, this approach is unusual but that is what was requested.

Comment: As mentioned in your last paragraph, I also believe this to be most natural approach. That the proofs in this approach turn out to be difficult is what I consider bit unusual.

Comment: I remember discussing the definition of $e^x$ some years ago.  Initially, I favoured one based on an important property such as Fred's answer.  However, I was convinced that the power series was the best definition and the other potential definitions should be theorems.  Less intuitive but probably easier overall.

Answer (score 9):

You can also define the exponential function like this:
$$
e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f_n(x)}{f_n(-x)}
$$
where
$$
f_n(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(2n-j)!}{j!(n-j)!}x^j
$$

Comment: I have never seen this one, and it's interesting, could you please relate this somehow to the usual definitions?

Comment: @MichalDvořák - it's using Pade Approximants. The Pade approximant for $e^x$ for any orders (numerator and denominator) are well-known. I've just used the approximants for equal order numerator and denominator, which turns out to be relatively neat. Basically, for a given $n$, this formula will give the same Taylor expansion as $e^x$ for the first $2n$ terms.

Answer (score 7):

Let $D_n$ be the number of permutations of $[n]$ without fixed points (i.e. derangements). Define
$$
\frac{1}{e}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{D_n}{n!}.
$$

Answer (score 7):

The exponential function is the unique smooth group isomorphism from the additive group of reals to the multiplicative group of positive reals whose derivative at zero is one.
It is the Lie group exponential map of the latter group.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: thanks to @HagenvonEitzen's comment.

I've often wondered if the following is sufficient for a general power function:

$$f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$$

And then:

$$f(1) = e$$

for the base.

Think this is probably similar to @badjohn's answer.

EDIT: thanks to @CarstenS and @R

Turns out we must also demand that $f(x)$ is continuous or measurable.

Comment: Not without also demanding continuity. Take any [additive $T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377638/additive-function-t-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-that-is-not-linear) with $T(1)=1$ and set $f(x) = \exp(T(x))$.

Comment: @CarstenS: You can get by with weaker conditions than continuity. For example, measurability suffices (and, with additivity, of course implies continuity).

Comment: @R.., yes I should have written "not without additional conditions".

Comment: $f(-x)=\frac1{f(x)}$ is redundant as it follows from the first and the fact that $f$ is not identically zero

Answer (score 5):

$e^x := \cos(-ix) + i  \sin(-ix)$

(See [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula))

Comment: Is it possible to define the sine and cosine of a complex number without using exponential?

Comment: That's a good question!  It seems like Euler's formula would be meaningless if it were not possible to define sin and cos for imaginary numbers.  Perhaps the Taylor Series would make sufficient definitions?

Comment: Sine and cosine can be defined by the corresponding power series. But this seems a bit like running in circles...

Comment: @weee all depends on where you start!

Comment: So we keep running in circles and going "@weee..."? =)

Comment: @weee Where else would one run when dealing with sin and cos? :)

Comment: In same vein as weee's comment we can define $\cosh$, $\sinh$ as unique solutions to diffeqs... but we are working hard to make this look this answer look different than Fred's when it's really the same. Perhaps a worthwhile connection is that the equation given here also clearly satisfies the IVP given in Fred's answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you've defined $a^b$, then you can take any sequence with a limit involving $e$ and define $e^x$ in terms of that. For instance, $$e^x=
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}
\left[
\frac{n!}{n^n\sqrt{(2n+\frac13)\pi}}
\right]
^{x/n}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Similar to above. It pops up in applying Euler's Method for solving differential equations numerically:

Suppose we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=ky.$ And we have $y(0)=1$.

By  Euler's Method:
Pick some small $\Delta x$. Then Let:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\Delta x$$
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{dy}{dx}\Delta x=y_n+(ky_n)\Delta x$$

With some rearranging: 
$$y_{n+1}=y_n(1+k\Delta x)\implies y_{n+p}=y_n(1+k\Delta x)^p$$
$$x_{n+p}=x_n+p\Delta x $$

Now we have that $x_0$=0 and $y_0=1$. So:
$$x_{n+p}=(0)+p\Delta x$$
$$y_{n+p}=(1)(1+k\Delta x)^p$$

Suppose we know we want our last value of $x$ to b $z$ and we want $p$ steps. Then we want $\Delta x$ to be $z/p$.

Then letting $n=0$,

$$y_p=(1+k\frac{z}{p})^p$$

By the limite mentioned above, $y_p$ gets closer and closer to $e^{kz}$ as $p$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Definition of $e$:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1.$$

Define an exponent as a supremum of a set of a real number to rational powers.

Comment: This needs a bit more elaboration as to how you define arbitrary real exponents.

Comment: Also, this seems to define $e$ but not $x\mapsto e^x$

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy, that is a definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

If we equip the one-dimensional manifold $(0,\infty)$ with the Riemannian metric $dx^2/x^2$, then the Riemannian exponential map at the point $1$ is the usual exponential function.
This is the unique metric that makes the exponential function an exponential map.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = e^x > 0$  is such a function that

$$ \int\limits_{1}^{f(x)} \tfrac{1}{u} \, \mathrm{d}u \ = \ x$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple geometric construction which produces $f(x)=e^x$.

Take two objects on a flat level surface, one at the point $(0,0)$ and the other at $(0,1)$, that are connected by a piece of string. Slide the top object along the horizontal line $y=1$. The horizontal displacement of this object is given by $x$, and the trajectory of the bottom object (the path of least resistance) is called a tractix.

After sliding $x$ units horizontally, draw the line segment of length $1$ which is parallel to the string and which contains $(0,0)$ as one of its endpoints. The second point of this line segment lies on the unit circle. Draw a line through the circle endpoint and the point $(1,0)$. The $y$-intercept $b$ of this line is equal to $e^x$, and the point $(x,b)$ belongs to the graph of the exponential function $f$.

Here is an animation I made using GeoGebra: https://youtu.be/zzvwGl9WpX8

Answer (score 0):

Similar things have been said, but not in that way:

$\exp$ is the only fixed point $f$ of the derivative (seen as function $D: C^{k+1}(\mathbb R) \to C^{k}(\mathbb R)$ for some $k \in [0,\infty]$, or between some other convenient spaces) which satisfies the normalization $f(0)=1$. (The set of all these fixed points is the one-dimensional eigenspace of $D$ for eigenvalue 1, and $\{\exp\}$ is a somewhat "canonical" basis for that space.)

Answer (score -4):

Here's an "unusual" one: $e$ is the positive real number such that

$$
\sqrt{6\log\left(e\sqrt[4]{e}\sqrt[9]{e}\sqrt[16]{e}\sqrt[25]{e}\ldots\right)} = \pi.
$$

Comment: Would you post some reference on this? This seems very interesting.

Comment: @MichalDvořák - it's just representing $\sum \frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}6$ in a really obtuse way. And it doesn't really define $e$ at all, since the logarithm has to be defined in terms of some base, and the $e$ just needs to match the base.

Comment: @GlenO Correct. I posted this as a "joke answer", so obviously this is not a definition. But does it deserve a downvote?